Definition of $P'$-torsion elements of an $R$-module
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Let $M$ be an $R$-module. The following context is in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra about localizations of modules.

The element $m/1$ is zero in $M_P$ if and only if $rm=0$ for some $r\in R-P$, so localizing at $P$ annihilates the $P'$-torsion elements of $M$ for primes $P'$ not contained in $P$. In particular, localizing at $(0)$ over an integral domain annihilates the torsion subgroup of $M$.

I am confused about the definition of $P'$-torsion elements as mentioned above. I guess, it means that
$$
\mathrm{Tor}_{P'}(M)=\{\ m\in M\ |\ \exists\,r\in P'\ \text{s.t.}\ rm=0\ \}.
$$
By assumption, $P'\not\subseteq P$, so $P'\cap(R\setminus P)\neq\varnothing$. But then considering $m_0\in M$ for which is annihilated by some $p_0\in P\cap P'$ ($P'\not\subseteq P$ can not conclude that $P\cap P'=\varnothing$ so such $m_0,p_0$ may exist), I can not conclude that there exists some $r\not\in P$ such that $rm_0=0$ so that $m_0/1=0\in M_P$.

Obviously it means $r \notin P'$ in that context. So your definition is not correct, hence the confusion. Notice that for $P'=0$ the condition then is $r \neq 0$ which may be more familiar for torsion elements.

Thanks for your answering, but I still have some doubts: if $m_0$ is a $P'$-torsion element with $p'_0m_0=0$ for some $p_0\in(R\setminus P')\cap P$, how can  we construct some $d\not\in P$ s.t. $dm_0=0$? If such $d$ does not exist then $m_0/1\neq0\in M_P$.
